# How to get Prettier to work with autosave and keep redo logs

Tags: visual-studio-code, formatting, prettier, redo

I'm using VSCode and i've been chasing an issue for some time. I've narrowed it down to prettier, thought I don't know how to fix it.

I use autosave extensively to quickly see changes in code through live server. I'd like to keep that if at all possible. I've tried turning format on save off and on, however it appears that so long as I have Prettier enabled, it touches my files and thus overwrites any redo logs.

I've only been using VSCode for about 8 months, and don't have all that much customized, but I do have a few other extensions. However, I've narrowed it down to prettier such that I get the functionality I expect (minus prettier) with it disabled.

I don't really want prettier to format or touch anything unless I press a key combination, so I'm not sure what is wrong. I've tried changing a few other things and looked online, but most everything says to check the "Format on Save" option. However, it doesn't matter whether it's ticked or not, so long as prettier is enabled.

Is there a way to explicitly tell vscode or prettier to only format when I press Shift+Alt+F ?